# How can I make my bot status say the time?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I tried this

```
 await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game(datetime.datetime.utcnow))
```

But instead it makes the status built in method utcnow of type object

This is probably a easy fix but this is my first discord bot sorry.

Answer (score 2):

If you are planning to update the time live (every second), please don't do this as the `change_presence` endpoint is heavily rate-limited and can easily get you  API banned if you spam it very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

```py
await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online,activity=discord.Game(start = datetime.datetime.utcnow))
```

you have two problems the first is that the date gets detected thru kwargs and without putting one it can not do so. the second thing is that you have to provide the name of the game [for more details click here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=activity#discord.Game)

Comment: Sorry it isnt working im not sure what im doing i am very new to this stuff... what would the correct code be if you dont mind ?

Comment: did you also add a name field?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `utcnow` is a method not an attribute so you have to put parentheses after it. Like this:

```py
datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

this will return the string that looks something like this: `'2021-08-19 10:20:05.359823'`

If you want to modify this string (for example display only hours and minutes) you can use the `strftime()` method. For example:

```py
datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%H:%M")
```

this will return string that looks like this: `'10:20'`

How your code should look like:

```py
await client.change_presence(
        status=discord.Status.online,
        activity=discord.Game(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%H:%M")),
    )
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help it fixed my problem! I have another question, for utcnow it displays the time (currently) as 1:23 AM. I want it to be my time zone which is 6:23PM right now. How would I go about this

Comment: try using `now()` instead of `utcnow()`. If this answer helped you please accept it with a tick under up/down vote buttons. I'm glad that I helped. You should also read WishyVish Ys answer to not get banned by discord.